# WSO2 ESB proxy service on Windows

Tags: proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

i'm using the WSO2 ESB to integrate several services on the Windows virtual machine.
I used the simple proxy to map the services deployed on it. But the problem is what i can't access them from outside it nevetheless the port 8280 where services are deployed is open for internet, but i can see only blank page instead. What could be wrong?
Another question is i was trying to map the WSO2 ESB management console itself to be availbe from outside the machine using simple proxy, and i'm failed, it loads me the [this is what i see on trying the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBnGd.png).

Could you please give me a hint on how to resolve this issue? is it possible to share the esb mgmt console using the ESB itself?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Do u have proxy in the middle? It looks like on screenshot webpage missing all pictures, meanwhile css was loaded successfully.

Another question which kind of virtual machine u use? For example in virtualbox by default virtual machine behind NAT.

I wasn't able to connect to server on virtual machine from host only opposite way server on host available in virtual machine.

To make server in virtual machine available on host need to configure network as bridge.

Comment: The virtual machine i'm using is a Windows servier 2008. I'm not sure about proxy, could be, it's not my machine, i'm just using it for the integration sake. in case of proxy is there any way to resolve the issue?
The same issue with the service provided by .jsp file, but this is even worse, i can't see the context of the page even on the same machine. just a blank page.

Comment: Did u check firewall settings? Port 8280 can be by default blocked on Windows Server

Comment: it is open since i can access it, but there is something wrong. For instance i can open the page myservername:8280/services/ with the list of the deployed services, but they available only as wsdl... maybe i did something wring, and really simple page deployed for the test sake on Tomcat port 8002 and then exposed by ESB on the port 8280 wich is just index.html page could be seen from my PC in the same way as on Virtual machine, but more complex thing as wars deplyed on AS are not.

Comment: Use SoapUI tool to identify problem with service. U will be able to get extra details about http connection logs

Comment: I don't think it would help, analizing the services, debugging the blank page in browser i see what there is errors but there is no any response. I think it is a matter of the ESB configuration which mess somehow...

Comment: At u can ensure that is it network problem (socket exception, connection timeout exception, what headers looks like)

Comment: I can't get at all access to virtual host behind NAT. Only if network interface configured as bridge.

Comment: On screenshot of webpage u provided above, can u open developer tools of browser and open network tab to see what is going on in there. Any error, connections are dropped?

Comment: i do not know how to add an image to this thread, can we swith to the private chat in gmail? ldobriakova75@gmail.com? Thanks!

Comment: I sent invitation to u

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get any invitation :(

Comment: Try mine uleming@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but I think I had a similar problem in our corporate network after I applied all the security patches (poodle,Diffie-Hellman etc.). I had to configure the addresses in catalina.xml (if i remember right) that are/under which allowed to access the admin console. Cannot tell you more details because I'm on holiday :-)

Maybe it's worth to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i'll take a look, but if u can provide me more details when u back from the holidays i would really appreciate this!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just checked the configuration and in carbon.xml I had to add the server name to the whitelist. Here an example:

Comment: <CSRFPreventionConfig>
                     <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                     <Rule>allow</Rule>
                     <Patterns>
                           <Pattern>carbon/sequences</Pattern>
                          .....
                           <Pattern>registry/resource/</Pattern>
                     </Patterns>

Comment: <WhiteList>
                           <Url>https://localhost:9443</Url>
                           <Url>http://localhost:9763</Url>
                           <Url>https://esbservername:9443</Url>
                           <Url>https://fqnesbservername:9443</Url>
                     </WhiteList>
        </CSRFPreventionConfig>

Answer (score 0):

Another example from real life. HTTP Response from external resource was application/json, status of response 200 OK.   ESB configured to use

```
    <messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                      class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
```

but content was simple text/plain.

During parsing body of http response exception was thrown  and just silently was written to log, without any fault message processing. Just empty response to client.

To clarify that services reachable, there is echo service by default on server, which respond content equal to request. Try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

> was trying to map the WSO2 ESB management console itself to be availbe
>   from outside the machine using simple proxy

By default the management console tries to enforce the port 9443 for dynamic links (JSP) pages. That's why you see only part of the pages and you shouldn't be able to log on.

what you can do is edit the repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml and to the Connector running the port 9443 you can add an attribute **proxyPort="443"**, the carbon console will be happy to run on 443.

For the services, my educated guess would be on the firewall / network rules, however without other information I cannot answer (or - they are working, just you may not try to access them by simple browser request)

Comment: In fact i'm not able, it gives me an empty page after i put the credential in the login/password fields.
I changed the catalina-server.xml as u suggested and restarted the WSO2, but it didn't help, i still see the partially loaded page only, no one image was able to be loaded, and probably not only them. 
Just to add, i try the same thing on the VM ubuntu on Vitrual box just to eliminate the proxy, firewall issues and get the same behaviour, the WSO2 management console is not loaded on the same PC exposed by ESB. What other details i can provide to get suggestion?

Comment: Can you see the HTTP communication from your browser? (usually F12 gives you the the dev console). Aren't you just redirected to "localhost" or another port? Please see this doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Setting+Up+Host+Names+and+Ports